# Does increasing NumEntryGuards decrease anonymity?

Tags: anonymity, guard

I get too many guard overload fails and tried increasing NumEntryGuards and NumDirectoryGuards both to 3.

Would this decrease my anonymity?

Answer (score 0):

Here are the entries from the [manual](https://2019.www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en).

> **NumEntryGuards NUM**
>
> If UseEntryGuards is set to 1, we will try to pick
> a total of NUM routers as long-term entries for our circuits. If NUM
> is 0, we try to learn the number from the
> guard-n-primary-guards-to-use consensus parameter, and default to 1 if
> the consensus parameter isn’t set. (Default: 0)
>
> **NumDirectoryGuards NUM**
>
> If UseEntryGuards is set to 1, we try to make
> sure we have at least NUM routers to use as directory guards. If this
> option is set to 0, use the value from the
> guard-n-primary-dir-guards-to-use consensus parameter, and default to
> 3 if the consensus parameter isn’t set. (Default: 0)

Neither will directly affect your anonymity though it is certainly not be a bad thing. Please see the [**FAQ**](https://2019.www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#EntryGuards) about this:

> Suppose the attacker controls, or can observe, C relays. Suppose there
> are N relays total. If you select new entry and exit relays each time
> you use the network, the attacker will be able to correlate all
> traffic you send with probability around (c/n)2. But profiling is, for
> most users, as bad as being traced all the time: they want to do
> something often without an attacker noticing, and the attacker
> noticing once is as bad as the attacker noticing more often. Thus,
> choosing many random entries and exits gives the user no chance of
> escaping profiling by this kind of attacker.
>
> The solution is "entry guards": each Tor client selects **a few relays
> at random** to use as entry points, and uses only those relays for her
> first hop. If those relays are not controlled or observed, the
> attacker can't win, ever, and the user is secure. If those relays are
> observed or controlled by the attacker, the attacker sees a larger
> fraction of the user's traffic — but still the user is no more
> profiled than before. Thus, the user has some chance (on the order of
> (n-c)/n) of avoiding profiling, whereas she had none before.

How many is "a few"? I don't know. It doesn't say. If you are not seeing 3 now and you raise it to 3, then it's not going to hurt anything. If you are seeing more than that, then it lowering it to 3 could make problems per the FAQ.